# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'User'

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, cluster-computing

Creating a cluster scheduled tasks on clustered servers. When i am trying with run as user it is not working.Some one can help me on this.

```
$username = "peopleAD\satest-BC"
$password = "password1234"

$TriggerParam = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At (7 am)

Register-ClusteredScheduledTask -Action (New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute E:\ScheduledTasks\SCHTEST.exe) -TaskName "SCHTEST" -Cluster WDSTGCL02 -Description "SCHTESTesting" -TaskType AnyNode -Trigger $TriggerParam -User $username -Password $password
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because `-User` and `-Password` are not valid parameters for that cmdlet. If you had run a simple `get-help` for it you could have seen that for yourself.

I would suggest running:

```
get-help Register-ClusteredScheduledTask -full
```

So that you can familiarize yourself with the cmdlet that you are using, and how to properly use it.

Answer (score 0):

**Register-ClusteredScheduledTask** does not take *Username* and *Password* as paramaters. It will however accept an existing *CimSession* to a remote computer. This can be setup as follows.

```
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username , ($password| ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force))
$CimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $Computer -Authentication Negotiate -Credential $creds
Register-ClusteredScheduledTask -Action (New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute E:\ScheduledTasks\SCHTEST.exe) -TaskName "SCHTEST" -Cluster WDSTGCL02 -Description "SCHTESTesting" -TaskType AnyNode -Trigger $TriggerParam -CimSession $CimSession
```

Comment: Even Though i am using Active directory credentials,  task is running under NT authority\system.Task Scheduler successfully finished "{38ea5583-65ab-4032-b336-6d28b6347658}" instance of the "\Microsoft\Windows\Failover Clustering\SCHTEST" task for user "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM".

Comment: What does your code looks like now? Can you update the question please?

Comment: $username = "ABCDDOMAIN\Sa-stguser" 
$password = "Password"
$Computer = "SJC04s1CL02"
$TriggerParam = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 7am 
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username , ($password| ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force))
$CimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $Computer -Authentication Negotiate -Credential $creds
Register-ClusteredScheduledTask -Action (New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute E:\SCHTEST.exe) -TaskName "SCHTEST" -Cluster SJC04s1CL02 -Description "SCHTESTesting" -TaskType AnyNode -Trigger $TriggerParam -CimSession $CimSession

Comment: OK, I see what is going on. You connect to the scheduler as user "ABCDDOMAIN\Sa-stguser" and register the task. By default a scheduled task will run as SYSTEM account. To make it run as a different user you need to change the task definition. However there is no way, that I can see, to do it through Register-ClusteredScheduledTask. Register-ScheduledTask can do it.